# how to compare strftime values

Tags: python, python-2.7, strftime

I have two values created from strftime as below

```
TIMEFORMAT="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

time1 = time.strftime(TIMEFORMAT)
time2 = time.strftime(TIMEFORMAT)
```

now the values of time1 and time 2 are like `"2013-11-22 04:03:56" "2013-11-22 01:03:56"`

The values are written by other script to file. And I am reading these values back from file and then comparing.

I want to compare something like this

```
if time1 > time2:
    # do etc. etc.
```

How to compare these times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can compare them. And, yes, `t1 > t2`.

```
In [1]: t1 = "2013-11-22 04:03:56"

In [2]: t2 = "2013-11-22 01:03:56"

In [3]: t1 > t2
Out[3]: True

In [4]: t1 < t2
Out[4]: False

In [5]: t1 == t2
Out[5]: False
```

Comment: Had no idea that we can directly compare.

Comment: Note that you can only directly compare them because your format allows it -- the most significant unit of time, the year, is at the beginning, and the least significant, the second, is at the end. (with everything else in the proper order in between) ALSO, to be absolutely precise, this probably won't work correctly for years before 1000 or after 9999, because `%Y` isn't zero-padded.

Comment: To reinforce the comment by @pandubear - this is not comparing the dates based on an interpretation of the date/time information, it is a simple lexical comparison of the strings. Thus, if you use a different format (e.g. the typical American `%m-%d-%Y`), it will fail. See the answer by @greg for a more robust method that interprets the strings as the data they represent before comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps you:

```
In [1]: from datetime import datetime, timedelta

In [2]: nd = datetime.now()

In [3]: pd = nd - timedelta(hours=1)

In [4]: snd = nd.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

In [5]: spd = pd.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

In [6]: print(snd, spd)
('2013-11-22 15:21:22', '2013-11-22 14:21:22')

In [7]: datetime.strptime(snd, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") > datetime.strptime(spd, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
Out[7]: True
```

Comment: yes. I thought to compare something like this initially but didn't knew syntax to format back to datetime and compare. Thanks. This is certainly helpful even if the case is that formats are different.

Answer (score 0):

I use GNU-Awk (gawk) in UNXUTILS on a Win-7 PC. This answer to the strftime(.) question raises a small puzzle of its own. I have a similar problem. In financial market data I have a date-time string ($25) given as "03-APR-2006 09:55:25" (so time = substr($25, 13, 8)) and my objective is to count records (especially order cancellation records) that come in after 14:00:00 (2 pm).

In my code I have a line which reads

```
         { if ($3==3) { 
                       { ++CK_NR} 
                       { ++CO_NR[$4, substr($25, 1, 11)] }  
                       { if (strftime(substr($25, 13, 8)) > ("14:00:00"))\
                         {
                          { ++CK_LATE_NR }
                          { ++CO_LATE_NR[$4, substr($25, 1, 11)] }
                         }
                       }
                      }
         }
```

Just realized that the inequality I used -- **if (strftime(substr($25, 13, 8)) > ("14:00:00"))** -- has only a string in the RHS, **and I didn't make this string the argument of another strftime(.). What's puzzling is that it did NOT give me an error.**

Am concerned that while it has not generated any errors, and the code has run, perhaps it is giving me something other than what I intended with the code. In a Command Prompt Window, doing

```
      \>gawk "{ print (strftime(\"09:55:25\") > (\"14:00:00\")) }"
```

does yield "0" and

```
      \>gawk "{ print (strftime(\"09:55:25\") < (\"14:00:00\")) }"
```

does yield "1". The GNU Awk Manual (http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Time-Functions) yields little information on what is required for a meaningful comparison. Just now tried the above deleting the "strftime" even from the LHS, as under

```
      \>gawk "{ print ((\"09:55:25\") > (\"14:00:00\")) }"
```

and

```
      \>gawk "{ print ((\"09:55:25\") > (\"14:00:00\")) }"
```

and got the same results. So while I offer this as a candidate "answer," **I want to be sure that I am getting the correct True/False result because GAWK is comparing time, and not for some other internal rule it uses in making string comparisons (causing the limited test to be only a coincidence).** Can someone resolve this puzzle? Thanks. Best,

Murgie

Comment: I think you should ask this as an independent question - there's definitely no __awk__ tag on this question. You may miss your target audience - not to mentioning the fact that your "answer" is off-topic

Answer (score 0):

That's a great example from user1907906

If people have a fix time with string to compare with, we can do as follows

```
# appointment_date is the datatime object
appointment_date < datetime.strptime("2022-04-21", "%Y-%m-%d")
```