# awk; comparing time -- puzzling behavior of strftime

Tags: datetime, awk, gawk, strftime

Use GNU-Awk (gawk) in UNXUTILS on a Win-7 PC. This question deals with strftime(.) and a comparison of times using that.

Have followed the discussion on [how to compare strftime values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143456/how-to-compare-strftime-values) because I have a similar problem. In financial market data I have a date-time string ($25) given as "03-APR-2006 09:55:25" (so time = substr($25, 13, 8)) and my objective is to count records (especially order cancellation records) that come in after 14:00:00 (2 pm).

In my code I have a line which reads

```
{ if ($3==3) { 
 { ++CK_NR} 
 { ++CO_NR[$4, substr($25, 1, 11)] }  
 { if (strftime(substr($25, 13, 8)) > ("14:00:00"))\
  {
    { ++CK_LATE_NR }
    { ++CO_LATE_NR[$4, substr($25, 1, 11)] }
  }
 }
}}
```

Just realized that the inequality I used -- **if (strftime(substr($25, 13, 8)) > ("14:00:00"))** -- has only a string in the RHS, and I didn't make this string the argument of another strftime(.). **What's puzzling is that it did NOT give me an error.**

Am concerned that while it has not generated any errors, and the code has run, perhaps it is giving me something other than what I intended with the code. In a Command Prompt Window, doing

> gawk "{ print (strftime(\"09:55:25\") > (\"14:00:00\")) }"

does yield "0" and

> gawk "{ print (strftime(\"09:55:25\") < (\"14:00:00\")) }"

does yield "1". The GNU Awk Manual (http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Time-Functions) yields little information on what is required for a meaningful comparison. Just now tried the above deleting the "strftime" even from the LHS, as under

> gawk "{ print ((\"09:55:25\") > (\"14:00:00\")) }"

and

> gawk "{ print ((\"09:55:25\") > (\"14:00:00\")) }"

and got the same results. I want to be sure that I am getting the correct True/False result because GAWK is comparing time, and not for some other internal rule it uses in making string comparisons (causing the limited test to be only a coincidence). Can someone resolve this puzzle? Thanks. Best,

Murgie

Comment: You are using string comparisons. For more information, see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Variable-Typing

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using string comparisons. Strings are compared by comparing the first character of each, then the second character of each, and so on. Thus, "10" is less than "9", since the ASCII value of "1" is less than that of "0", see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Variable-Typing and http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/An_Awk_Primer/Search_Patterns_%282%29#Logic_Operators

If you want to do numeric comparison for strings on the form "xx:yy:zz" (for instance "10:22:45") then you can try to convert the string to a number first using `gsub(/:/,"",str)`

Comment: I was not intending a string comparison. But a comparison of times. strftime(.) gave me a reasonable answer, but what puzzled me was that it did so even when used in only one side of the inequality!! That was what led me to worry about whether it was merely coincidence. But will read your references soon. Thanks.