# new file name each time python run

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using python 2.7..

I am using below to send all print output to a file called output.log.  How can i have this send to a different file each time it runs...In bash we could declare a variable called date or something and have that part of the file name...so how can i achieve the same with python ??

So my question is..

1. every time i run the below script, my file should have a naming convention of  output_date/time.log
2. Also how can i delete file that are older than X days that have a file naming convention of output_*.log

   ```
   import sys
   f = open('output.log', 'w')
   sys.stdout = f
   print "test"
   f.close()
   ```

Comment: look up the `time` and `logging` modules. https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with some personal preference of formatting this is generally what I do.

```
import time
moment=time.strftime("%Y-%b-%d__%H_%M_%S",time.localtime())
f = open('output'+moment+'.log', 'w')
```

as far as automated deleting, do you want it deleted on run of the test?

```
os.remove(fileStringName)
```

works, you just have to do the arithmetic and string conversion. I would use os.listdir(pathToDirWithOutputLogs) iterate through the file names and do the math on them and call os.remove on the old ones.

Answer (score 2):

To get date/time:

```
from time import gmtime, strftime

outputFileName = "output_#.log"
outputFileName = outputFileName.replace("#", strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
```

For numerical incrementing:

```
outputFileName = "output #.log"
outputVersion = 1
    while os.path.isfile(outputFileName.replace("#", str(outputVersion))):
        outputVersion += 1
    outputFileName = outputFileName.replace("#", str(outputVersion))
```

To delete files older than a certain date, you can iterate through all the files in the directory with ``, and delete them with `os.remove()`. You can [compare the file names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143456/how-to-compare-strftime-values) after parsing them.

```
lastTime = "2015-08-03_19:04:41"
for fn in filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir()):
    strtime = fn[fn.find("_"):fn.rfind(".")]
    if strtime < lastTime:
        os.remove(fn)
```